# Why is ampersand being interpreted as children on text node

Tags: java, xml, dom, blackberry

I have an xml file that I am parsing and I have the following tag...

```
<desc>
/wap/news/text.jsp?sid=242&nid=5662369&cid=5038&scid=-1
</desc>
```

I don't have control over the format of this xml file but I need to interpret the desc content as a partial url that I will later append to a base URL and retrieve a new file.

When I parse this the desc tag has one child, a text node with a value of...

```
/wap/news/text.jsp?sid=242
```

but the rest of the line is parsed as 6 child nodes on the above text node with values of...

```
&
nid=5662369
&
cid=5038
&
scid=-1
```

How do I make the parser treat this as just a single text node and not interpret the '&' symbols as child nodes.

The relevant parsing code is below.

```
HttpConnection c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(inURL.toString(), Connector.READ);
is = c.openInputStream();
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
factory.setAllowUndefinedNamespaces(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
document = builder.parse(is);
```

This is J2ME code on a blackberry so I'm pretty limited as to the APIs I have available.

Comment: Correction: The rest of the line is not being interpreted as attributes but as child nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is a special character in XML. It needs to be escaped as `&amp;`.

If something is producing the above text file, then it's not producing valid XML.

Comment: Valid or not sometimes we are stuck dealing with what we have at hand.

Comment: Let me guess - someone decided to piece together this psuedo-XML manually instead of using a proper XML library? And now you've got to live with those results? Anyway, if you really need to use an XML parser to parse not-XML, you could replace the relevant `&` s with `&amp;` s before feeding it into the parser.

Comment: @whatnick - expecting an XML parser to do something sensible with invalid XML is analogous to expecting a Java compiler to do something sensible with C.

Comment: Yes I can't do anything about the XML. Its not mine and they won't fix it. The slurping into a buffer and fixing pre parse sounds like the best option. I'll give that a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm. I just slurp the file into a buffer and do an XML escape pass before sending to the parser. There were many more problems than what I showed. Their files are a mess but its working now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Maven: Just check that you don't get `&ampamp` in your expansions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your original XML code is not valid XML, that is one reason it could fail you. Second, Java by default does not coalescates the fragmented text content. I have written a blog entry about the details of this, and how you are able to merge the different text nodes by setting a property on the parsing factory:

http://www.drillio.com/en/software-development/java/fragmented-xml-text-nodes/